# Where can I find the paper from Yakubovich (Jakubovic) on S-procedure

Tags: optimization, control-theory

in control theory, many articles refer to the following paper:
V. A. Yakubovich, S-procedure in nonlinear control theory, Vestnik Leningrad University, 4 (1977), pp. 73-93.
english translation; original Russian publication in Vestnik Leningradskogo Universiteta, Seriya Matem-
atika (1971), 62-77.

Unfortunately I wasn't able so far to find it anywhere on the internet/my library. Can anyone provide my with a link or copy of this paper? That would be of great help!

Comment: You can have a look at "A Lecture on the S-Procedure" by Ulf Jönsson on the topic. It contains a lot of information about it. I have never been able to find the paper you mention.

Comment: @KBS thanks for your help1